# Pros and cons of using integer programming alone or combined integer and global optimization?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, global-optimization, integer-programming

First, I am not sure if this is the right question to ask in this forum. But I have been looking for answers for a long time and I have been also asking my university's "engineering" professors but I don't seem to get a mathematical answer.

I am trying solve a complex optimization problem involving network and short path optimization and at the same time solve for non-linear pressure, flows and diameter. I can apply one of the following methods:

1. The first method is to use a Mixed Integer Linear Programming method
   (MILP) only and linearize the pressure, flows and diameter using
   piece-wise linear approximation. The linearization is done since the
   MILP only takes linear equations and look for an optimal solution.
2. The second method is to use a combined local optimization and global
   optimization method. The local optimization would use MILP first to
   find solution to sub-problems where continuous optimization would be
   costly to use (e.g. allocation of production ). Then, I would use a
   global optimization method using derivative-free genetic algorithm
   to perturb the system (e.g. the network path) and
   find a better global solution. Every time the system is perturbed,
   the local MILP optimization is repeated.

I am after any recommendations, heads-up and things to watch out for if I implement one of these two methods. Is the second method mathematically acceptable compared to the first method?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve? Is this a flow optimization problem? A routing problem to find where to send the follow to a certain location? I am still trying to understand what your objective function would be.